# SwiftUI @State variable not assigned in time

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to show 2 sheets. One of them takes an argument.
This code crashes when I try to show the second sheet, because the forcefully unwrapped argument was not assigned. This happens even though I assign it before I update the variable that triggers the showing of the sheet.
How can `someArgument` still be nil?

This is all the code needed to reproduce the error:

```
enum ActiveSheet: Identifiable {
    case first, second

    var id: Int {
        hashValue
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var activeSheet: ActiveSheet?
    @State var someArgument: String?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                activeSheet = .first
            } label: {
                Text("Activate first sheet")
            }

            Button {
                someArgument = "Show this text"
                activeSheet = .second
            } label: {
                Text("Activate second sheet")
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: $activeSheet) { item in
            switch item {
            case .first:
                FirstView()
            case .second:
                SecondView(message: someArgument!)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FirstView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello I'm 1")
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    let message: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(message)
    }
}
```

I suppose that the reason this is not really straight forward is because NavigationLinks are usually used for this kind of use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible fix is to pass your argument string as an associated value of the `ActiveSheet` enum.  That way, it will be available at the same time the enum is initialized:

```
enum ActiveSheet: Identifiable, Hashable {
    case first
    case second(String)

    var id: Int { hashValue }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var activeSheet: ActiveSheet?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                activeSheet = .first
            } label: {
                Text("Activate first sheet")
            }

            Button {
                activeSheet = .second("Show this text")
            } label: {
                Text("Activate second sheet")
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: $activeSheet) { item in
            switch item {
            case .first:
                FirstView()
            case .second(let someArgument):
                SecondView(message: someArgument)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FirstView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello I'm 1")
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    let message: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(message)
    }
}
```